# How to create a general-purpose VisualForce page that can appear on any layout?

Tags: layout, salesforce, visualforce

VisualForce pages can have the format:

```
<apex:page standardController="Case" >
  <div id="content"></div>
  <script>
      ... javascript to render a UI into #content ...
  </script>
</apex>
```

which means it can appear on the "Case" layout. If you want a generic VisaulForce page (appearing all alone on a tab, let's say) you can remove the standardController parameter:

```
<apex:page>
...
</apex>
```

Is there a way to specify that a single VisualForce page can appear anywhere? (In our case, it's a javascript utility which is not layout-dependent).

I'm new to SalesForce, and the closest I could come up with would be to dynamically populate the standardController field (if that is supported) but I feel there must be a better way. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean it's a piece of javascript you can include in other pages? If so you should be doing it as a component, or you could put the JS in a static resource and include that in your pages.

If it's actually a page, you can include it in a page layout as well, though it's a little clunky and goes in an iFrame so that would probably cause problems for you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! The VisualForce page is a <div> tag and some javascript which renders a UI (along with event handling). It doesn't interact with the outer page and works inside an iFrame currently.

The issue is that I can't seem to create a general-purpose <apex> wrapper which can be used on any layout along with regular tabs. I'm not sure if I'm approaching this the right way, though.

Comment: Like I said, you can insert a VF page inline into a standard page layout, I think that's probably you best option. Or is it that you just want it to have it's own tab?

Comment: Yes, some clients will use it inside a layout, but others might put it in its own tab. Ideally, we'd like to use the same VisualForce page for both.

Comment: Just to clarify, it seems a VisualForce page only appears in the Layout Editor if it has the standardController specified. I can't seem to add an arbitrary page inside an iFrame.

Comment: yes, the standard controller must match object type. You might not use it but it must match. @LaceySnr is right, create component and reuse it in two pages.